# What's the best way to enable SUBSELECT / JOIN when using spring-data-jpa

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

After reading some threads, I just realised that it's not possible to use @Fetch(value = FetchMode.JOIN) in spring-data-jpa, whatever mode used, it always ends with N+1 query. Shouldn't JPA provide some way to address this problem?
Thanks in advance!
PS: I'm using spring-data-jpa 1.10.2 with hibernate 5.0.9

Comment: Personally I always control the fetching in individual query, instead of defining in the entity.

Comment: @AdrianShum could you show me how to control the fetching in individual query? btw, it turns out to be that FetchMode doesn't work only in case the parent - child relationship is not built on primary key

Comment: something like `@Query("from Foo foo left join fetch foo.bar left join fetch foo.qux where foo.name=:name")`

Comment: I see, thanks a lot!